# parse statement string for arguments using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have user input statements which I would like to parse for arguments. If possible using regex.

I have read much about functools.partial on Stackoverflow where I could not find argument parsing. Also in regex on Stackoverflow I could not find how to check for a match, but exclude the used tokens. The Python tokenizer seems to heavy for my purpose.

```
import re

def getarguments(statement):      
    prog = re.compile("([(].*[)])")
    result = prog.search(statement) 
    m = result.group()  
    # m = '(interval=1, percpu=True)'
    # or m = "('/')"
    # strip the parentheses, ugly but it works
    return statement[result.start()+1:result.end()-1] 

stm = 'psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=True)'
arg_list = getarguments(stm) 
print(arg_list) # returns : interval=1, percpu=True

# But combining single and double quotes like
stm = "psutil.disk_usage('/').percent"
arg_list = getarguments(stm) # in debug value is "'/'"   
print(arg_list) # when printed value is : '/'

callfunction = psutil.disk_usage
args = []
args.append(arg_list)
# args.append('/')
funct1 = functools.partial(callfunction, *args)
perc = funct1().percent
print(perc)
```

This results an error :
builtins.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'/'"

But

```
callfunction = psutil.disk_usage
args = []
#args.append(arg_list)
args.append('/')
funct1 = functools.partial(callfunction, *args)
perc = funct1().percent
print(perc)
```

Does return (for me) 20.3 This is correct.
So there is somewhere a difference.

The weird thing is, if I view the content in my IDE (WingIDE) the result is "'/'" and then, if I want to view the details then the result is '/'

I use Python 3.4.0  What is happening here, and how to solve? 
Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Your "'/'" vs '/' problem sounds like you're viewing the result in two different ways. Viewing a variable in the interactive prompt by typing its name by itself on a line can give you a different result than if you explicitly use a `print` function. How are you viewing the contents of `arg_list`? An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be just terrific here :-)

Comment: As input string to functools.partial which fails with  "'/'" but not with '/'. And using my IDE as debug tool.

Comment: So is that a "no" for an MCVE, then...?

Comment: @ Kevin, you are right, I will make a MCVE. Sorry Kevin. Please wait a few minutes.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of arguments in `arg_list`?
`["'\'"]` or `["interval=1, percpu=True"]` or `["interval=1", "percpu=True"]`
vs. `"'\'"` and `"interval=1, percpu=True"`
what about this one line regular expression?
`re.findall("\((.*?)\)", stm)`

Comment: @Kevin I changed the code to MCVE. You are right, there is a difference between looking the value when debugging, and when printing.

Comment: The string `"'/'"` will be printed as `'/'`. it's normal ;)

Comment: @Mehdi, is used your one line regular expression, which is better then mine. Thanks. But it still generates " '/' ". Which will fail when using as input for functools.partial. With which code can I convert " '/' " to '/ '? That is the core of my problem.

Comment: it's not safe, but you can try: `print(eval("'/'"))`

Comment: @Mehdi, print(eval("'/'")) does work. But the statement string is user input. Using eval is much easier then functools.partial, but eval is not save like you mentioned. I do not want to use eval.

Comment: Can I pop up a level and ask, if you're parsing user arguments, why you're reinventing the wheel (and making your code into some black magic) with hand-coded regular expressions, instead of using [cement](http://builtoncement.com/) or [clint](https://github.com/kennethreitz/clint) or [cliff](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/cliff/) or [cli](https://pythonhosted.org/pyCLI/) or [clime](http://clime.mosky.tw/) or [docopt](http://docopt.org/)?This is Python, after all, not Perl!

Comment: @charlesreid1 I have two requirements, which are (a bit) contradictory. Use a much as possible existing code. Parsing a statement have to be done by Python itself, so may be some methods could be re-used, but I could not find it.
The other requirement is to limit dependencies as much as possible. Using code snippet, as from Mehdi and Alik is Ok. And keep is simple.
Your suggestions are all not part of the Python code, so generating additional dependencies. This is really a big issue for me.
My impression is that your suggestions are very powerful, and will
make my application future proof.

Answer (score 1):

`getarguments("psutil.disk_usage('/').percent")`  returns `'/'`. You can check this by printing `len(arg_list)`, for example.

Your IDE adds `"`, because by default strings are enclosed into single quotes `'`. Now you have a string which actually contains `'`, so IDE uses double quotes to enclose the string.

Note, that `'/'` is not equal to `"'/'"`. The former is a string of 1 character, the latter is a string of 3 characters. So in order to get things right you need to strip quotes (both double and single ones) in `getarguments`. You can do it with following snippet

```
if (s.startswith('\'') and s.endswith('\'')) or 
        (s.startswith('\"') and s.endswith('\"')):
   s = s[1:-1]
```

Comment: no there is a difference. I added functools.partial code. '/' does return a correct number (a percent), But " '/ ' " returns an error code.

Comment: @Bernard because `'/'` is not equal to `"'/'"`. The former is a string of 1 character, the latter is a string of 3 characters. You need to modify your regular expression, so it strips single quotes

Comment: that is possible. I tried that, (hardcoded) and it works. But then my previous statement But the input is user code, which can be anything. It can also be ' "/" '

Comment: But then 

stm = 'psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=True)'  will fail. I was searching for a elegant pythonic solution.

Comment: @Bernard Why would it fail? How did you strip quotes?

Comment: just hardcoded : arg_list_stripped = arg_list[1:len(arg_list)-1] What I am missing is when to strip or not. This can get a very error-prone direction. I try to avoid this.

Comment: @Bernard `if (your_str.startswith('\'') and your_str.endswith('\'')) or (your_str.startswith('\"') and your_str.endswith('\:')): your_str = your_str[1:-1]`

Comment: your answer does work. Could you add your comment in the answer, then I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Bernard, before you accept, let me give you two more mean examples. Then tell me if they can occur and if this code properly resolves them. `'someFunc(("mean", "tuple")).meanSecond("function")'` and `'someFunc(1, \'4=2*2\', arg1="4,5")'`

Comment: @swenzel this is why `ast` should be used, not regexps.

Comment: @Alik Yes, exactly! If you know it already why don't you say it? :D Regex cannot count and therefore there is no reliable way to find the closing brackets. But since we don't know how complex the user input can get, it is hard to say if this possibility has to be considered at all.

Comment: @swenzel OP mentioned, that a python parser might be overkill for his problem, so I thought, that he doesn't have to deal with complicated calls. Anyway, this is a good example of parsing function calls with `ast` module - http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576671-parse-call-function-for-py26-and-py27/

Comment: Still worth mentioning it ;) Imho there is no way around `ast`. The next problem is almost certainly to call `psutil.cpu_percent` using `'interval=1, percpu=True'` since it is a string that needs proper evaluation to be used as kwargs for that function. Nice link by the way, looks pretty close to what OP needs!

Comment: @Alik Thanks for both replies. The user gives the input string which must be an expression with, after execution, a atomic result. So psutil.disk_usage('/') returns a NamedTuple so is not allowed. But psutil.disk_usage('/').percent is, because it returns a float. The user defines the string, so I can not know for sure it will be as complex as you mentioned. For the moment not. But I will keep your remark to the ast module and the complex parsing for if it will be required.